# How to run Validation on all the items at once (Sitecore7.2)?

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm not able to save and publish the main page due to validation error on some connected old subitem. How do I enforce validation on all the items in order to find the wrong item? Currently, I'm getting a popup message with the error and without the specific item name. I don't want to go item by item because there are thousands...

Comment: Can't you find the place where message is displayed and add (temporalily) an item's name to it?

Comment: Cannot edit the rule on PROD directly, it is not reproducible on the other environments. Thanks for the answer, will have to dig through the DB.

Comment: What about writing name to a log file? It won't be visible to user.

Comment: Solved it through the DB with a few joins, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it through the DB with a few joins in order to find the items with the specific validation rule and its value.